# 3 Column Div Style

Tags: html, css

For some weird reasons I can't get this to work properly (for a 3 Column layout)they are showing as if they are on different lines.
-------------------CSS-----------------

```
.left_content{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:30%;
    padding:10px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    background-image: url(../images/right_divider.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;   



}


.center_content{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:40%;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:10%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;
    background-image: url(../images/right_divider.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;   

}
.right_content{
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    padding:10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;
    background-image: url(../images/right_divider.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;   

}
---------------html--------------
<div class="left_content">
    Nav Left
    </div>


    <div class="center_content">
    main Con<br>main Con<br>main Con<br>main Con<br>main Con<br>main Con<br>main Con<br>
    </div>


<div class="right_content">
    right Con
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@frank; as you see in your code that the total width of three `div's` is more then `100%`. Reason because `padding` & `border` are add width to the div. So, you can use css3 `box-sizing` property for this. it's stop padding to add width to the div.

**css:**

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

check this example http://jsfiddle.net/wVfeG/

*NOTE*:  IE7 did not support `box-sizing` property. So, you can remove `padding` from your div & give `margin to it's child`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="left">
Port side text...
</div>
<div id="right">
Starboard side text...
</div>
<div id="middle">
Middle column text...
</div>
<div id="footer">
Footer text...
</div>
</body>
And here's the CSS code:
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
div#header {
clear: both;
height: 50px;
background-color: aqua;
padding: 1px;
}
div#left {
float: left;
width: 150px;
background-color: red;
}
div#right {
float: right;
width: 150px;
background-color: green;
}
div#middle {
padding: 0px 160px 5px 160px;
margin: 0px;
background-color: silver;
}
div#footer {
clear: both;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

OR 
Below link for you 
(http://www.neuroticweb.com/recursos/3-columns-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

You should watch the column-width/column-gap from CSS3 :)
http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

Answer (score 0):

If you give

`margin-left:10%;` then you have to reduce the `.center_content` class width as 35.